# Setting default value for date columns with FeatureClassToNumPyArray in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, numpy

I am reading a feature class into a pandas dataframe using:

```
df = DataFrame(
    arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray(
        in_table=feature_class,
        field_names=field_list,
        skip_nulls=False,
        null_value=np.NaN
    )
)
```

Where `feature_class` is the name of the feature class and `field_list` is the list of fields to include.

Setting `skip_nulls=False` ensures the floats are converted to `np.NAN` and setting `null_value=np.NAN` does the same for integers. However, one of the columns has a date type, which causes the following error:

> ValueError: year 0 is out of range

Is there any way to set a specific default for the date type?

Comment: Have you tried without numpy: `df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(feature_class, field_list),columns=field_list)`

Comment: That actually works pretty well! Thanks @BERA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on @BERA's solution, a more robust function to read tables/feature classes into dataframes would be:

```
def to_dataframe(data, field_list=None, exclude=None):
    """
    load data into a pandas data frame for subsequent analysis.
    :param data: input arcgis feature class or table.
    :param field_list: fields to be used.
    :return: pandas dataframe object.
    """
    # if empty, get field list from data
    if field_list == None:
        fields = arcpy.listfields(data)
        field_list = [f.name for f in fields]

    # Build dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
            data=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(data, field_list),
            columns=field_list,
            exclude=exclude
            )

    return df
```

This method coerces dates, and also turns the `SHAPE` field into a tuple of points.

Comment: you should mark your own answer as the answer so other can see a solution was found.